# Two papers that abbreviate to the same Author et al (1999) in text

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

I have two citations like

```
@ARTICLE{Openshaw1999a,
  author = {Openshaw, S. and Turton, I. and Macgill, J},
  title = {Using the Geographical Analysis Machine to Analyze Limiting Long-term
    Illness},
  journal = {Geographical and Environmental Modelling},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {3.1},
  pages = {83-99},
  owner = {ijt1},
  timestamp = {2010.09.27}
}
```

and

```
@INCOLLECTION{citeulike:8468480,
  author = {Openshaw, Stan and Turton, Ian and Macgill, James and Davy, John},
  title = {{Putting the Geographical Analysis Machine on the Internet}},
  booktitle = {Innovations in GIS 6},
  publisher = {Taylor and Francis},
  year = {1999},
  editor = {Gittings, Bruce},
  chapter = {10},
  pages = {121--132},
  address = {London}}
```

which both appear in the text as “Openshaw et al (1999)” when I cite them. Other than using `[fullnamesfirst]` as an option to `natbib` is there a way to prevent them appearing to be citations of the same paper?

Comment: to clarify I'm trying to avoid using the full citation as this is an abstract and space is limited so I'd like to get Openshaw et al (1999a) and later (1999b).

Comment: This should be the default with `natbib` style such as `plainnat` or `abbrvnat`. What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: I was using chicago but on switching to apalike it does work as I'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing the two papers as "Openshaw et al (1999a)" and "Openshaw et al (1999b)" implies that those papers were written by the same co-authors, while in fact one author (John Davy) was part of the second, but not of the first author team. (Herbert's use of the `alpha` style avoids this problem.) Using author-year-styles, I would cite the papers as "Openshaw, Turton et al (1999)" and "Openshaw, Turton, Macgill et al (1999)". I'm not aware of a bibliography style that will do so automatically (disambiguation of author lists is on the roadmap for future versions of `biblatex`). Using `natbib`, you could define

```
\defcitealias{key1}{Oppenshaw, Turton et al (1999)}
\defcitealias{key2}{Oppenshaw, Turton, Macgill et al (1999)}
```

and write

```
\citetalias{key1,key2}
```

in the text, but this solution is far from perfect (`\citepalias` would result in double parentheses).

UPDATE: Disambiguation of author names and name lists was implemented in `biblatex` v1.4, released on March 31st, 2011. See section 4.11.4 of the `biblatex` manual for details. Have a look at the following example with the package option `uniquelist=true`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=1,uniquelist=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Openshaw1999a,
  author = {Openshaw, Stan and Turton, Ian and Macgill, James},
  title = {Using the Geographical Analysis Machine to Analyze Limiting Long-term Illness},
  journaltitle = {Geographical and Environmental Modelling},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {3.1},
  pages = {83-99},
  owner = {ijt1},
  timestamp = {2010.09.27},
}
@incollection{citeulike:8468480,
  author = {Openshaw, Stan and Turton, Ian and Macgill, James and Davy, John},
  title = {{Putting the Geographical Analysis Machine on the Internet}},
  booktitle = {Innovations in GIS 6},
  publisher = {Taylor and Francis},
  year = {1999},
  editor = {Gittings, Bruce},
  chapter = {10},
  pages = {121--132},
  location = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison see the output of the same example with `uniquelist=false`:

[image]

Comment: I wish I could give you a second vote for the update

Answer (score 1):

use the star version

```
foo~\citep*{Openshaw1999a,citeulike:8468480}
```

[image]

Comment: The two citations appear in different paragraphs and I'm using author-year citations

Comment: @iant: use `\citeyear` then and `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`

Answer (score 1):

[`biblatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/215) can do some of what you want. In fact, it will automatically add 1999a or 1999b with the `style=authoryear` style. This will not, however, deal with the problem lockstep mentioned: viz, the disambiguation of author lists. You could set the `maxnames=4` option, and this would disambiguate the author lists, but that's probably suboptimal...